# Show last post in category

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I just edit the topic details.

I am currently in the process of developing a Forum, which consists of 4 entity:
- Category which includes several forums
- Forum which brings together several topics
- Topic comprising several Posts
- Post which contains answers to topics

Everything works fine for now but one point at a query that I can not achieve.

I would like on the home page of the forum all the categories with sub forums to allow rapid navigation.
The problem I have is that I can not retrieve the post dernirer performed for each forum, and I would like to know how I do for solve this problem ?

So I would like to display all categories associated with all these forums and post the last post in the entity so LastPost topic of each forum.

Here's an overview of what I would do : http://hpics.li/029d17b

My repository :

```
public function findAllCategory()
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->leftJoin('c.forum', 'f')
        ->addSelect('f')
        ->leftJoin('f.topic', 't')
        ->addSelect('t')
        ->orderBy('c.id', 'DESC');

    return $qb->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

My controler :

```
$categorys  = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Category')->findAllCategory();
```

Here is my twig file :

```
{% for category in categorys %}
    <div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12"><h2>{{ category.title }}</h2></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            {% for forum in category.forum %}
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h3><a href="{{ path('forum_rubric', { 'slug': forum.slug }) }}">{{ forum.title }}</a></h3>
                    {{ forum.description }}

                    Last Post :<br/>
                    {% if forum.lastPost is not empty %}
                        <a href="{{ path('forum_topic_show', { 'slug': forum.topic.slug }) }}#message-{{ forum.lastPost.id }}">{{ forum.topic.title }}</a>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

My entities :

```
class Category
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Forum", mappedBy="category")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    private $forum;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"title", "id"})
     * @ORM\Column(length=128, unique=true)
     */
    private $slug;
}


class Forum
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Category", inversedBy="forum")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $category;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Topic", mappedBy="forum")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    private $topic;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"title", "id"})
     * @ORM\Column(length=128, unique=true)
     */
    private $slug;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Post")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    private $lastPost;
}


class Topic
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="topic")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Forum", inversedBy="topic")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $forum;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Post", mappedBy="topic")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    private $post;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"title", "id"})
     * @ORM\Column(length=128, unique=true)
     */
    private $slug;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime")
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Post")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    private $lastPost;
}


class Post
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="post")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Topic", inversedBy="post")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $topic;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="message", type="text")
     */
    private $message;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime")
     */
    private $createdAt;
}
```

Thanks !

Comment: It's not clear what is the question about and what is the problem you are stuck on. Please can you provide some more information about the problem itself?

Comment: Sorry but I do not see how to be more precise ... My problem is that I do not manage to recover the last post in each forum.

I put a picture of what I want to do, but here I do not see how to deal with the request not to recover the last post